# Is the ability to see enemy healthbars while deploying Mercy's ultimate a bug or feature?

Tags: overwatch

Mercy's ult, Valkyrie, boosts all her abilities, but one feature that I never see anywhere mentioned, or anyone talking about, is how she can see enemy healthbars while the ult is active. Is this a bug or an intended feature?

I ask because it's a bizarre and unfitting buff for what her ult is themed around (boosting her **existing** abilities) and I literally don't see it anywhere even slightly mentioned. I can't be the only one to have noticed this, right?

*(Note: Apparently it has been changed, Mercy can only see enemy healthbars if one of her teammates damages the enemy.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature was changed in a [previous patch](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/17618042787):

> **USER INTERFACE UPDATES**
>
> Mercy
>
> - Valkyrie
>
>   - No longer shows enemies’ health bars unless they have taken damage
>
> **Developer Comments**: This helps remove some clutter from Mercy players’ screens when they use her ultimate

Probably not a bug if it's specifically mentioned in patch notes.